# How to get into an object that is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Let's say I have an array like this :

```
arrayOfObject = [{item: {this: is,  that: is}}, {item2: {this: is, that: is}}]
```

I'm trying to access item and item2 without having to use a 0/1 index. I'd like to be able to say arrayOfObjects[item] to get into the object. Is this possible?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong here, so it's hard to understand what exactly the structure is. But the bottom line is simple: when you need to address item by some arbitrary identifier, use Object (or Map). Otherwise you'll have to scan the whole array (with `.find()` or similar op) each time when trying to access specific item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do exactly this but something similar where you would "convert" your array to an object and then use the keys to access the values:

```js
arrayOfObject = [{ item: { this: "a", that: "b" } }, { item2: { this: "c", that: "d" } }]

const arrayToObject = arrayOfObject.reduce((r,c) => Object.assign(r,c), {})

console.log(arrayToObject['item'])
console.log(arrayToObject['item2'])
```

In the snippet above we convert the `arrayOfObject` to array**To**Object and then simply access the values via the keys.

Otherwise what you are trying to do is not possible since you can only access values from an array by index or via some kind of a function which would traverse it and get you the entry, like `find` etc.

Comment: Found this very helpful and exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Happy to help. If this was helpful please consider up-voting or simply accepting this as the answer. This would help other people having similar question finding the answer quicker.

Comment: Would love to but I am just shy of the reputation needed (I have 14!). Definitely will once my reputation is high enough. Thanks!

Comment: @fsp712 but you can accept this answer by clicking on right tick.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array.find.

```js
arrayOfObject = [{
  item: {
    this: 'is',
    that: 'is'
  }
}, {
  item2: {
    this: 'is',
    that: 'is'
  }
}]

console.log(arrayOfObject.find(ob => ob['item']));
console.log(arrayOfObject.find(ob => ob['item2']));
```

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Updated the code.. I think the OP is trying to tell us what the logic is without much caring about the syntaxes. But he should also care the syntax too IMO.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arrayOfObject = [{
    "item": {
        "this": "is",
        "that": "is"
    }
}, {
    "item2": {
        "this": "is",
        "that": "is"
    }
}];

var itemObject = {};
arrayOfObject.forEach(function(value) {
    var filterObject = Object.keys(value).filter(val => val.indexOf("item") != -1);
    if (filterObject.length > 0) {
        filterObject.forEach(key => {
            itemObject[key] = itemObject[key] || [];
            itemObject[key].push(value[filterObject[0]]);
        });
    }
});

console.log(itemObject.item); //item
console.log(itemObject.item2); //item
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure it is possible:

```
var result = arrayOfObject.map(a => a.item);
```

or

```
var result = arrayOfObject.map(a => a.item2);
```